# django Login page does not load

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-login

I am trying to make a login page using built-in Django login features. I created a button on the main page, which should redirect the page to login.html where I can log in. Once I click on the button, the URL changes accordingly(http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/), but the page itself(login.html) would not load.
Please regard the codes below.
Codes for urls.py in the created app

```
    
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from mainApp import views

    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^test/', views.test),
        url(r'^book/', include(('book.urls', 'book'), namespace="PB")),
        url('', views.mainIndex, name='mainIndex'),
    
        url('account/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Codes for settings.py

```
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'mainApp',
        'book',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    )

    MIDDLEWARE = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'mainApp.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mainApp.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
    LOGOUT_URL = '/account/logout/'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Finally, this is the code in my mainIndex.html

```
    {% if user.is_active %}
        {{ user.username }} Welcome!
        <button type="button" 
            onclick="location.href='{% url 'logout' %}'">
            logout</button>
    {% else %}
        <h3>Please Log In</h3>  
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: What does "_page itself(login.html) would not load_" mean, is it a blank page? Is it a 404 error page?

Comment: By default django tries to render registration/login.html, did you put login.html inside that folder ?